# Can't Install Google Chrome in centos 6.9

Tags: google-chrome, centos6.5

[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# **yum install google-chrome-stable**
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:63.0.3239.84-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.84-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest**
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]#